# Redirect doesn't work after insert batch codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem after inserting some data from array, the insert data works properly. But the Redirect doesn't work, I don't understand the error, because no error message show just the blank page, I have tried and tried until it become habit that makes me tired.

Here is the Function Controller that I use:

```
public function all() {
    $data       = array();
    $idkelas    = $this->input->post('kelas');
    $idabsen    = $this->input->post('idabsensi');
    $idabsen2   = $this->input->post('idabsen');
    $id         = $this->input->post('idsiswa');
    $hadir  = $this->input->post('hadir');
    $smt        = $this->input->post('semester');
    $jamke  = $this->input->post('jamke');

    $count      = count($id);
    // to absensi
    $this->db->query("UPDATE absensi SET jmlhadir = '$count' WHERE idabsensi = '$idabsen2'");

    // to absensidetail
    for($j=0; $j < (int)($count); $j++) {
        $data[] = array(
            'idabsensi'     => $idabsen[$j],
            'idsiswa'       => $id[$j],
            'statusabsen'   => $hadir[$j],
            'semester'      => $smt[$j],
            'jamke'         => $jamke[$j]
            );
        }
        return $this->db->insert_batch('absensidetail', $data);
        redirect('absensi/absen/pilihkelas/'.$idkelas, 'refresh');

}
```

This is the View:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>absensi/absen/all" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-large" value="ABSENT ALL" />
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>No. Induk</th>
                    <th>Student Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php $i=0 ?>
            <?php foreach($kel as $d):
            $i++;
            ?>
            <tr class="list-users">
                <td><input type="hidden" name="idsiswa[]" value="<?=$d->idsiswa?>" readonly><?=$d->idsiswa?></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="hadir[]" value="hadir" readonly><input type="hidden" name="jamke[]" value="<?=$jamke?>" readonly><input type="hidden" name="mapel" value="<?=$idmapel?>" readonly><?=$d->noinduk?></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="kelas" value="<?=$d->kelas?>" readonly><input type="hidden" name="semester[]" value="<?=$h_getsmt->idsemester?>" readonly><?=$d->namasiswa?></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="idabsensi[]" value="<?=$d->idabsensi?>" readonly><input type="hidden" name="idabsen" value="<?=$d->idabsensi?>" readonly><?=$d->jeniskelamin?></td><td><span class="label label-unabsent">unabsent</span></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a class="btn btn-mini dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Actions <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a ><i class="icon-pencil"></i>Press Button<BR>ABSENT ALL First</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td></tr>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </form>
```

I really hope someone can help me.
Thank You

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Yup, as @Mikolaj said there's something wrong with the locate  of the `redirect`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect would need to come before `return`

This is from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php):

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as
>   the value of the function call. return also ends the execution of an
>   eval() statement or script file.

You can also check out: [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Comment: I just tried The Redirect come before `return`. But the Insert Batch doesn't work. Anyway, thanks for the reference link its valuable for me, let me learn.

Comment: @Dindonfiqriaji `redirect` will send you to the page (you are redirecting to) before `return` can be executed. You might consider not `return`'ing and instead calling the object (minus `return`) and then the `redirect`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return` from the statement for batch insert. If there is `return`, it will not go to the next statement written for redirection.

Update it like this.

```
$this->db->insert_batch('absensidetail', $data);
redirect('absensi/absen/pilihkelas/'.$idkelas, 'refresh');
```

Comment: Its work! How can just remove the `return` ? arghh I was thinking over night over day about it. I really don't think about remove the `return`. Oh I'm feel I must learn much much much more. Thank you very much....